# Text in disabled round textured NSButton is not greyed out

Tags: cocoa, nsbutton

I have an `NSButton` created in Interface Builder with the style "Round Textured". When the button is disabled, the text colour does not go grey as you would expect. Oddly enough when the button contains an image instead of text, the image does go grey, as seen in the below screenshot (top buttons are enabled, bottom buttons are disabled).

[image: enabled and disabled buttons]

How can I get the text to go grey when the button is disabled?

**Update:** So it gets weirder: the view containing the button is shown in a popover and every second time the view is shown the button is greyed out.

Comment: I can suggest a workaround for this issue, you can NSButton's AttributedTitle property and modify the text color as you wish

Comment: @SheenVempeny I've tried this and it doesn't work. Setting the title colour while the button is enabled works fine, but as if the button is disabled it ignores the custom colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, at least in Yosemite, as long as you set `button.wantsLayer = YES` on the button view, that it then works. Go figure.